# Cloud Function taking to long using https.OnRequest and Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase SDK on my website. Its Write and Get speed is perfect. 
But, while testing cloud functions to be able to read on my firestore I see it is taking 5-7 seconds to find one record, while using Firebase SDK it's im ms

The main purpose of why I want to use firebase functions over firebase SDK get method is cache. I want to cache results since It's records wont change so often.

Here is my code so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.fetchStore = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const gotData = []
  admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('person_id', '==', `${req.query.q}`).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = {
          name: doc.data().name,
          dept: doc.data().dept,
          position: doc.data().position,
          person: doc.data().person_id

        }
        gotData.push(data)
      })
      res.send(gotData)
    })
});
```

Since cache is my main purpose here even though I am not doing anything up there. Yet, but what is bothering me is the 7-10 second response time. So is there any other way to do this better ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the root cause, but you aren't properly ending the function execution.  Per the Firebase documentation, "Always end an HTTP function with `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`. Otherwise, your function might to continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system."  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events.

Comment: @ScottKronheim you are right, I was tired of multiple tries so I uploaded here a wrong code... even though now using ''${req.query.q}` instead of saving the req.data.q seem's to do the trick a bit, now I have a 150-250ms response time